# A specific value(only one) to be first in a query result. Rest order by time stamp

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-order-by

I have a search result query for posts. And I want posts written by myself(userId = 27) to be first in query result and rest ordered by time stamp. Can anyone give me query for that in mysql?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
select *
from posts
order by 
  if (userid=27, -1, any_timestamp_include_zero);
```

include your full table schema help much better

Comment: How do specify if ii should be ASC or DESC?

Comment: you can assign a very big numeric number for DESC, or a very small numeric number for ASC

Answer (score 1):

How about something like:

```
select * from post
order by 
    case 
        when userid = 25 then '0001-01-01 00:00:00' 
        else my_timestamp
    end
```

(formatting the '0001-01-01' part appropriately for MySql)

Answer (score 0):

Something simple like this:

```
SELECT * FROM POST WHERE userId = 25
UNION
SELECT * FROM POST WHERE userId <> 25 ORDER BY TIMESTAMP_FIELD
```

Could work for your need?

Comment: it didn't worked wihtout paranthesis for the wuery before and after "UNION"