# Ordering AA before A

Tags: mysql, database, sql-order-by

I'm doing an e-commerce website for a client who sells lingerie, I've written up a bra size picker for them but they've come back to me today with a slight issue.

With bra sizes, AA is smaller than A, so it should appear before that in the chart, but when I use MySQL order by on the size, obviously it puts A first, then AA, then B etc.

Is there a simple way I can get MySQL to order AA first, then A, B etc.?

Comment: why not have another column, `size_in_number` or may be `size_in_cm`, then use a query like `order by size_in_number`? Given you provide smaller size, smaller number.

Comment: See also [A specific value(only one) to be first in a query result. Rest order by time stamp](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4570872/a-specific-valueonly-one-to-be-first-in-a-query-result-rest-order-by-time-stam).

Comment: Add an additional column SortOrder of type int, I usually have a SortOrder field on all my entities used in select lists.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming `A` is the only possible repeating letter, you can do this:

```
SELECT  *
FROM    bra
ORDER BY
        LENGTH(size) DESC, size
```

But a better solution would be to create a conversion table which would store all possible sizes (European, Japanese etc) including metrical on which yoг can order.

You may use it to build conversion charts and show the sizes in person's preferred system as well.

Comment: This is perfect for what I need. Some of the other answers were good too but this is nice and simple. I have a sort_order field already but the products are pulled through from a SOAP web service connected to their EPOS system, way too many to manually enter sort orders. Thanks all!!

Answer (score 4):

I would add another column "orderid" (INTEGER or even TINYINT) to your table, and order by that column instead.

Answer (score 1):

Would putting and underscore before "A" so "_A" work and be acceptable, you could strip it for display purposes? (Not sure if this will work or not)

Alternatively have a sort code seperate from the bra size field for sorting.

Answer (score 1):

Create a lookup table for the ordering

```
Table bra_order
id integer auto_increment not null
bra_size char(3)
sort_id integer not null
```

Then do something like:

```
SELECT i.* FROM inventory
LEFT JOIN bra_order b ON (b.bra_size = i.bra_size)
ORDER BY b.sort_id
```

Answer (score 0):

> You can order by a value derived from a column. You can use a CASE
>   operator to specify the order: ...

[source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2005350/mysql-order-by-issue)

this would be your select:

```
select id, val 
from test 
order by 
case val
 when 'AA' then 1
 when 'A' then 2
 when 'B' then 3
END
```

sorts AA first, then A then B :)

Answer (score 0):

I would prefer to introduce a column `sequenceNo` to store the order on the server. Imagine other pickers

- XS
- S
- M
- L
- XL
- ...